Context is empty in AWS Quarkus Lambda Handler
I used quarkus-amazon-lambda extenstion to make a lambda handler. I made a really basic one just to test.
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
// ...

public class LambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<Map<String,String>, OutputObject> {
    public OutputObject handleRequest(Map<String,String> event, Context context) {
        LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();

        // log execution details
        logger.log("ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES: " + gson.toJson(System.getenv()));
        logger.log("CLIENT CONTEXT: " + context.getClientContext());
        logger.log("CONTEXT: " + gson.toJson(context));

        // process event
        logger.log("EVENT: " + gson.toJson(event));

        return new OutputObject();
    }
}

My problem is that in local dev my Context object has stuff in it, but not in the deployed version. When I invoke my lambda from CI/CD or the AWS console, my Context object is an empty (not null) json. Then event is sent correctly to the handler.
When looking at the logs, I saw that the io.quarkus.arc.impl.RequestContext was activated, then destroyed, then deactivated, before the first log was printed.
Example log from AWS console :
date TRACE [io.qua.arc.requestContext] (main) Activate new
date TRACE [io.qua.arc.requestContext] (main) Destroy id
date TRACE [io.qua.arc.requestContext] (main) Deactivate
...
START RequestId: id Version: $LATEST
ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES: {...}
CLIENT CONTEXT: nullCONTEXT: {}EVENT: {...}
...

I tried adding to the application.yaml to have more infos, but the logs don't really help.
quarkus:
  log:
    category:
      "io.quarkus.arc.requestContext":
        min-level: TRACE
        level: TRACE

I'm looking to understand how AWS injects the context in the handler, how Quarkus is managing this Context, and why my context object is empty. Thanks :)
